# Term for a story that is a perfect loop

Tags: terminology

Is there a noun for or an adjective that describes stories that can be read from beginning-to-end repeatedly? That is, the beginning of the story is a seamless continuation from its ending. You could copy paste the story infinitely many times in a row and it would be totally coherent. One example is the song ["There's a Hole in My Bucket"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket) that brings you back to the starting point.

Comment: “*A Day in the Life of Sisyphus*”

Comment: One version of this is the “recursive” story. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night. This is not referenced in the so-called duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhalgren) describes Samuel R. Delany's novel *Dhalgren* as a "circular text". This seems to me like a fairly good name, and I expect you're not going to find a better one.

*Dhalgren* is indeed a member of the class of texts you're looking for; it ends and begins:

> Waiting here, away from the terrifying weaponry, out of the halls of vapor and light, beyond holland and into the hills, I have come to
> to wound the autumnal city. So howled out for the world to give him a name. The in-dark answered with wind.

(Although maybe "totally coherent" isn't the best way to describe either *Dhalgren* or *Finnegans Wake*, which are both circular texts.)